# Find the best upper bound of $\varepsilon$ such that $g(x) = 1 + \varepsilon f(x) > 0$, $f(x)$ bounded on a closed set?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, upper-lower-bounds

Consider a smooth function $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, consider:

$$g(x) = 1 + \varepsilon f(x),$$

for $x \in [0, 1]$ and some $\varepsilon > 0$.

Which are the conditions on $\varepsilon$ which guarantee that $g(x) > 0$? I guess the answer is something in the form:

$$0 < \varepsilon < M,$$

for some $M > 0$.

---

**My attempt**

Let $[0, 1] = I^- \cup I^+$, where:

- $f(x) < 0 ~\forall x \in I^-$;
- $f(x) \geq 0 ~\forall x \in I^+$.

For $x \in I^+$, then $g(x) > 0$.

For $x \in I^-$, since function $f$ is (smooth, then) bounded, then:

$$\exists F > 0 : f(x)>  -F ~\forall x \in I^-.$$

Therefore:

$$g(x) = 1 + \varepsilon f(x) > 1 - \varepsilon F ~\forall x \in I^-.$$

If $\varepsilon < \frac{1}{F}$, then:

$$1 - \varepsilon F > 0,$$

and hence

$$g(x) > 0 ~\forall x \in [0, 1].$$

---

**Questions**

Is there some easies way to achieve this kind of results?

Is there any better upper bound for $\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than you think. You just need that your function is continuous. Indeed, since $f$ is continuous, for the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) $f$ must attain a maximum $M$ and a minimum $m$.
Then (SPOILER)

> $$ 
> g(x)\geq 0 \quad \forall x\in [0,1] \Leftrightarrow
> 1+\varepsilon f(x)\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow 1+\varepsilon m\geq 0
> $$
>   If $m=0$, it's obvious that $g(x)>0$, otherwise we select $\varepsilon >0$ such that 
>   $\varepsilon\geq \frac{-1}{m}$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) \ge 0$, then $1+\epsilon f(x) > 0$ for all values of $\epsilon$.

If $f(x) < 0$, then

\begin{align}
   g(x) > 0 
   &\iff 1 + \epsilon f(x) > 0 \\
   &\iff \epsilon f(x) > -1 \\
   &\iff \epsilon < -\dfrac{1}{f(x)}
\end{align}

So $\displaystyle \epsilon =  -\max_{f(x)<0} \dfrac{1}{f(x)}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Then, can I take the lowest between $$-\min_{f(x)<0} \dfrac{1}{f(x)}$$ and $$-\frac{1}{\min_{f(x)<0} f(x)},$$ right?

Comment: I had to rethink my answer and change it. That should be $-\frac{1}{\max_{f(x)<0} f(x)},$

Comment: In that case, your answer is the same of the one provided by Andrea Cavaliere.

Comment: Yes. I just did the logic differenly.